# Display live HTML/Javascript demo in web page embedded

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

I have a blog hosted freely on blogger. I want to show some html live demo, as my tutorial is about javascript and html. Can anyone suggest, how it can be done, i have to display sample javascipt page based on Extjs.

It should be embedded inside the post, like how we paste the code using code syntax highlighter.

Something similar to this demo:  http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel

**Edit-1**

As per @Circadian, i have used jsFiddle.net but it is giving entire code too, as shown in the image attached. But I don't want to share my entire code. Any other better suggestions?  [image].

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no way to have HTML and javascript on a page that a user can not see.

Comment: @jbabey. User can see is fine.. But as you see in the attached image. I dont want in with all jsfiddle style. just want a output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) offers iframe embedding and supports Extjs

**edit**:

then have a look at using [github gists](http://gist.github.com)

Comment: i have used jsFiddle.net but it is giving entire code too, as shown in the image attached. But I don't want to share my entire code.